# Ambiguous error for created_at on joins query

Tags: sql, ruby, activerecord

I have an active record query that is causing an ambiguous error for `created_at`.
The query is:

`Payment.joins(:invoice).successful.where('created_at < ?', 1.hour.ago)`

The is aiming to return any successful payments that have invoices where the payment created at is older than an hour.
However due to the `.joins(:invoice)`, it is getting confused about the 'created_at' scope as both invoice and payment have a created_at column.

An alternative i have tried is:
`Payment.joins(:invoice).successful.where(created_at: *code for older than an hour ago that im unsure on*)` or `Payment.joins(:invoice).successful.where('self.created_at < ?', 1.hour.ago)` however i can't seem to get the syntax correct.

Is there any way to solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prefix the column with the table name, in this case `payments`;

```
Payment
  .joins(:invoice)
  .successful
  .where('payments.created_at < ?', 1.hour.ago)
```

Notice that your attempt to use `self` won't work because whatever you pass to `where` as a string is "interpreted" as raw SQL - what they refer to as "a SQL fragment". `self` is a Ruby keyword with no use in your RDBMS.

Comment: In newer versions of rails this could be converted to `where(payments: {created_at: ...1.hour.ago})`